# Are there self-service laundries in Arendal?

Tags: norway

Are there any self-service laundries, or similar, in Arendal? I'm traveling to the Hovefestival for 10 days and would like to wash my clothes halfway through the week.

Comment: You can always do laundry in a hotel sink, if necessary.

Comment: @Flimzy Forgot to say that I will be staying in a tent.

Comment: ok, in a bucket then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of question can generally be answered by translating the term into the local language, then searching for it.

Launderette is *Vaskeri* in Norwegian according to Google translate.  Searching for *Vaskeri Arendal* has various results including a business directory:
http://www.nettkatalogen.no/bransjelist/vaskeri%20arendal/1.htm

And just to confirm there's not a translation error, searching for the address of one of those vaskeris gives the following image in Google street view http://goo.gl/maps/VeYWK (zoom in to the store behind the parking sign).  Looks like a place to wash stuff (rather than a store selling washing machines).

Of course, there is no guarantee it is still there.

Comment: Great investigation.